# Turning active M-! into M-& (a'ka emacs equiv to bash Ctrl-Z)

Tags: commands, process, async

From time to time I happen to `M-! some_command` just to find that the command runs longer than I expected and keeps my emacs frozen for long seconds. So I glaze at my frozen emacs and kick myself for not using `M-& some_command` and promise myself to use `M-&` next time. But `M-!` is in my muscle memory for decades…
And of course there is `Ctrl-G`, but there are cases when breaking command and re-running it is not preferable (mayhaps it may break sth, mayhaps would be costly to rerun…).

Similar mistake in shell konsole is trivial to correct, `Ctrl-Z`, `bg` and job is running in the background.

Does there exist some similar trick in emacs -  a way to turn currently running foreground (synchronous) command into backgroundized (asynchronous) one?

Note: in case it is impossible for *default* `M-!`, I am open to suggestions of how to rebind `M-!` into something else (what would be functionally equivalent apart from this trick).

Comment: You may be interested to know that simply adding an `&` to the end of a regular `shell-command` (`M-!`) will make it asynchronous. Of course, you must do this before running a command, but at least you can use the same keybinding.

Comment: You could always just remap `M-!` to `async-shell-command`. :-) Seems like the only thing you lose is getting the output in the echo area when it is short enough.

Comment: @nanny, in fact, that's all `async-shell-command` does. It adds an `&` to the end of the `COMMAND` string and executes `shell-command`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does there exist some similar trick in emacs - a way to turn currently running foreground (synchronous) command into backgroundized (asynchronous) one?

I suspect no such trick exists. The problem is that the synchronous shell command (which is really `call-process-region`) blocks the emacs event loop. The only way to break it is to kill the process with a USR1 or USR2 signal or do <kbd>C-g</kbd>. (There may be other ways, but that's what I do).

This means there's nothing you can do because you don't have a way to invoke the trick, as Emacs does not process input while the event loop is stalled.

---

One thing you *can* do is simply swap the keys:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "M-!") #'async-shell-command)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-&") #'shell-command)
```

Comment: Rebinding M-! to async-shell-command makes partial sense, but:
(1) I am not sure about M-1 M-! behaviour (command output to buffer) – simple fast cases work but what if the command is slower and I type sth?
(2) in many cases I like the _freeze until command finishes_ behaviour as it gives clear finish indication (some commands have no output…), therefore explicit keystroke „put to background” would be nicer
(3) async leaves those *Async* buffers which must be reaped

Comment: I am thinking whether some wrapper around async-shell-command would be possible to write (a function which would spawn async-shell-command, then wait for it's finish, react to Ctrl-G by aborting command and to some other keystroke by leaving it running but not waiting anymore, and reap *Async* buffer once done if output is empty or short). I am not sure how to do that waiting part…